# How to get an event from another program?

Tags: c#

I've got `Program A` which uses an external Library `Lib`. Then there is a second program `Program B`. `Program A` calls a function in `Lib` which triggers an event. This event must processed from `Program B`. How can I do this?

If I would try to load `Lib` dynamically at runtime from `Program B` this would create a new instance and so I wouldn't get the event triggert from the `Program A` - `Lib` instance. So the question is for me how is the best practice to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot communicate between two processes that way. Security being one thing, process isolation and more.

There are multiple alternatives to achieve what you want

1. Anonymous pipes
2. Named pipes
3. Sockets

Or if the communication is simple and trivial, a common persistence storage like a database or a file.

Documentation on anonymous pipes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-use-anonymous-pipes-for-local-interprocess-communication

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. I'll try it at the weekend.